# Why hibernate query methods (defined in repository interface) are not available?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a problem with Spring repository.

I'm defining  a query method and it's not available in repository instance.

Do I have to implement this method queries or add any dependencies?

UserRepository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findUserByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
}
```

method where I want to execute this query method:

```
 @PostMapping("/login")
    public String loginUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpSession session){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return "/login";

        User loggedUser = userService.getUserRepository().findUserByEmailAndPassword("email", "password");
}
```

And i get the message `Cannot resolve method 'findUserByEmailAndPassword' in 'JpaRepository'`. I tried to add `@Query` annotation with sql query parameter but it didn't change a thing

Comment: Add code instead of images

Comment: First of all please provide a code for the entity class and also you can try to replace findUserByEmailAndPassword with findByEmailAndPassword and check whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from your code, but based on the error message you're seeing I'm assuming that the return type of `userService.getUserRepository()` is `JpaRepository`, but `findUserByEmailAndPassword` is declared in `UserRepository`.

If that's the case, you will need to either cast the result of `userService.getUserRepository()` or change the return type to `UserRepository`.

Answer (score 0):

[§ 6.3.2. Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) says, that your method name should be:

```java
findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
```

instead of:

```java
findUserByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
```